# How to make all combinations from a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have a following dictionary:

```py
origin = {0: [1,2], 1: [1,2,3]}
```

I would like to get a dictionary that makes combination key_element in value. Desired output is:

```
{'combo_0_1': 0, 'combo_0_2': 0, 'combo_1_1': 0, 'combo_1_2': 0, 'combo_1_3': 0}
```

I tried this:

```py
output = {f"combo_{x}_{y}" : 0 for x in origin.keys() for y in origin.values()}
```

but it returns `{'combo_0_[1, 2]': 0, 'combo_0_[1, 2, 3]': 0, 'combo_1_[1, 2]': 0, 'combo_1_[1, 2, 3]': 0}` which is not what I want. How can I do it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using a dictionary comprehension over [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
origin = {0: [1, 2], 1: [1, 2, 3]}

res = {f"combo_{k}_{v}": 0 for k, vs in origin.items() for v in vs}
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'combo_0_1': 0, 'combo_0_2': 0, 'combo_1_1': 0, 'combo_1_2': 0, 'combo_1_3': 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

`origin.values()` returns all the values, which are lists. This is not what you want.

You want the elements of the current list.

```
output = {f"combo_{x}_{y}" : 0 for x in origin.keys() for y in origin[x]}
```

Comment: `for x in origin` is enough. No need to use `.keys()`. I would instead choose more meaningful variable names, like `for key in origin for val in origin[x]`

Answer (score 2):

It helps to write it out as a full loop first. We can convert it to a dict comprehension after that.

You want the second part of the key to be *each element* of each value of `origin`. You can get the keys and values of `origin` in one outer loop, and then in the inner loop, you can loop over the elements in that value.

```
origin = {0: [1,2], 1: [1,2,3]}
output = {}
for key, val in origin.items():
    for elem in val:
        output[f"combo_{key}_{elem}"] = 0
```

Or, as a dict comprehension:

```
output = {f"combo_{key}_{elem}": 0 for key, val in origin.items() for elem in val}
```

This gives:

```
{'combo_0_1': 0,
 'combo_0_2': 0,
 'combo_1_1': 0,
 'combo_1_2': 0,
 'combo_1_3': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. It generates all the permutations of your lists, and is generalized to accept longer dictionaries.

```py
import itertools

origin = {0: [1,2], 1: [1,2,3]}
perms = list(itertools.product(*origin.values()))
output = {f"combo_"+ "_".join(map(str,p)): 0 for p in perms}
print(output)
```

Note: You need to map the tuples which `itertools.product` generates to strings to join them together to your `"combo_"` keys. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not what is asked for... You are not using the keys. Have another read of the question (there's even an expected output)

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I understand how the keys and values relate now. I thought it was based on the permutations of the key lists. My mistake! :)